# EF Core Many to Many Relationship

Tags: domain-driven-design, efcore

I am thinking about using Entity Framework Core in a new project.  The project has a many to many relationship.  Entity framework Core does not allow shadow state entities as described here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368

There are two options for the design:

1) Create a CLR type for the junction table in the database.

2) Create a CLR type for the junction table in the database.  Then hide it using a fascade as described here: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-4-a-more-general-abstraction/

The junction table in the database contains foreign key attributes only.  I am interested to hear how others have approached DDD when using EF Core as the database.  Am I overthinking this? Is the answer just to use option 1 and forget about it?

Comment: 3) stick with SqlClient and other better ways to query databases

Comment: An ORM is a tool. I cannot recommend directly using the *data model* generated by EF as your *domain model*. With that in mind, we can see that your question has very little to do with DDD. Use whatever tools you would like behind your repositories.